# Customising url for solritas solr + velocity templates

Tags: solr

Im thinking the packaged velocity templates that come with solr will be easy enough to customise for my needs and its DAMN FAST so why mess with it.

My question is about the url/server setup.

Right now its http://1.2.3.4:8093/solr/browse

The way I see it, its not installed within an apache account on a LAMP server so I cant modify that accounts htaccess file.

What I want to do is have www.mysite.com delegate to the above instead. No port in the url, and no ip address obviously.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it from the examples just add the port to the start up parameter

```
java -Djetty.port=80 -jar start.jar
```

this will start up `SOLR` on port `80`.

If you've configured `Tomcat6` change the `server.xml` file to run on port `80`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tomcat just change the deployment descriptor to the Solr web application to

```
<Context docBase="C:\\apache-solr-3.5.0\\example\\solr\\solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="C:\\apache-solr-3.5.0\\example\\multicore" override="true"/>
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
</Context>
```

It's important not to have any 'path="/something"' attribute in the Context tag and you must make sure all other web applications will have a path="/something".

This will put Solr as the default web application hidding the path.